# 32bit JVM, ProcessBuilder.start() and ENOMEM

Tags: java, fork, processbuilder

One application I have to deal with regularly launches shell helpers using `ProcessBuilder`. For reasons untold, it still runs on a 32bit JVM (Sun, 1.6.0.25) even though the underlying OS is 64bits (RHEL 5.x for what it's worth).

This application is memory-happy, so the heap size is set to its maximum of 3 GB, and the permgen is 128M.

However... At random moments, shell helpers fail to launch. Not because of an OutOfMemory, but ENOMEM... The only cause I can see for this is lack of address space.

Well, sure, but at the same moment, the memory is not really under pressure and `top` reports that the actual memory usage of the JVM and its virtual set size, is not even 3 GB...

Looking at what can be looked of the code of `Process`, I see that the core method is called `forkAndExec()`, which is pretty much self explanatory... From what I know of both syscalls, it just shouldn't fail. But it does. And not always.

Why?

**edit**: it should be noted that neo4j is used. It seems to use FileChannel a lot, can that be the cause of lack of address space?

Comment: If I remember correctly, when spawning a new process, Linux will initially allocate same amount of memory to the new process as the parent process has. That allocation is immediately adjusted to the correct size. Is it possible that there is not enough memory available to allow for the initial sizing? I remember we had to solve this problem by allowing overcommitting memory in the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would decrease the heap size.  The amount of heap actually used could be leaving less and less space for the forked process to run (it inherits resources from its parent)

It is highly likely that just upgrading to a 64-bit JVM would fix the problem, Can you try Java 6 update 30 64-bit instead (just to see if it would fix the problem) If it does or does not, it should tell more about what the cause is (and then you can decide if its worth switching)

Comment: 64bit is in the plans... I definitely consider it, I was just wondering why the current version couldn't fork even with some address space to spare -- or not? See update, I think I may have found the cause

Comment: FileChannels use up file resources, but not address space so much.  If you had a 32-bit OS, your JVM would probably fail to start with a heap of 1.5 GB, so you are doing very well to have a heap of 3 GB, you certainly don't have much virutal space to spare.  Even trying a 2.5 GB heap might fix the problem.

Comment: I was rather thinking about the `MappedByteBuffer`s: they don't take heap space...

Comment: They don't take much heap (less than 1 KB) but they use virtual memory of course. Using MappedByteBuffers in a 32-bit process sounds pretty limiting. To compare what you can do with a 64-bit JVM http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-memory-mapped-file-for-huge.html

Comment: Very interesting... I didn't know mappings were limited in size. Thanks!

Comment: The size of a ByteBuffer is an `int` limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE unfortunately. The largest power of 2 they can be is 2^30 or 1 GB. You can make the mapping larger by using the underlying native calls (which don't have this limit), but its even uglier IMHO.  It matters in the example I give because it results in ~7450 mappings for the same file!

Comment: Unfortunately its 2^31-1, so almost. ;)

Comment: OK, well, @PeterLawrey, thanks for the informations, I guess 64bit has jumped up a few levels up on my todo list...

Comment: You might find this useful http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/07/java-all-about-64-bit-programming.html

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are being bitten by [Linux memory overcommits killing your processes.](http://opsmonkey.blogspot.com/2007/01/linux-memory-overcommit.html) That blog post suggest a sysctl variable that you can tune.

Comment: Well, no, the logs don't show the OOM killer being triggered... It really seems to be the fork syscall returning ENOMEM here